# ¿Cómo soluciono este problema de sobrecarga de corchetes?

Tags: c++, lista, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es comparar un string con un atributo de una clase "Aldeano" la cual es el nombre del aldeano, entonces todos los aldeanos que creo se guardan en una **lista de aldeanos (list<Aldeano< aldeanos)**, pero al momento de querer compararlos para ver si el string coincide con el nombre del aldeano, me sale el error de 'no match for operator []'. Como list no incluye una sobrecarga de [], intenté hacer una manualmente. Después de varios errores al momento de hacer la sobrecarga, ya no me da errores en la estructura de la sobrecarga, sin embargo el error principal de 'no match for operator []' sigue sin solucionarse a pesar de ya tener la sobrecarga de [], ¿tiene algo de malo la sobrecarga de corchetes? o ¿hay otra alternativa más fácil para la comparación?

Lo primero es la función en donde quiero comparar el string y en la linea del if es donde me da ese error. Lo segundo es el método e implementación de la sobrecarga de [] que hice. Y perdón si hice algo mal en el formato de stackoverflow, es la primera vez que hago una pregunta.

```
bool Civilizacion::modificarAVerificacion(const string &m)
{
     bool band=false;

     for(size_t i=0;i<aldeanos.size();i++)
     {
         if(m==aldeanos[i].getNombreA())
         {
             cout<<endl <<endl;
             cout<<left;
             cout<<setw(15) <<"Nombre";
             cout<<setw(10) <<"Edad";
             cout<<setw(10) <<"Genero";
             cout<<setw(10) <<"Salud";
             cout<<endl <<endl;
             cout<<aldeanos[i];
             band=true;
         }
     }
     return band;
}




///Esto va en una clase administradora
Aldeano& operator[](size_t n);


///Esto va en la implementación de esa clase administradora
Aldeano& Civilizacion::operator[](size_t n)
{
       auto it=aldeanos.begin();

       for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           it++;
       }

        Aldeano &a = *it;

       return a;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. ¿No sería más sencillo asignarle un id a un aldeano y comparar los id's? Por ejemplo, que el id sea un prehash del nombre, sirve que eso te ayuda a reducir el tiempo de búsqueda de `O(n)` a `O(1)` si utilizas un hashmap con ese prehash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias opciones para solventar el problema que tienes:

- En caso de querer utilizar "list" podrías recorrerlo mediante iteradores de esta forma:

  ```
   list<Aldeano> aldeanos;

   for (list<Aldeano>::iterator it = aldeanos.begin(); it != aldeanos.end(); ++it){
       cout << it->nombre;
   }
  ```
- También podrías optar por utilizar "vector" o alguna otra similar que te permite obtener directamente un elemento dado un índice utilizando el operador []:

  ```
   vector<Aldeano> aldeanos;

   int posicion = 0;

   cout << aldeanos[posicion].nombre;
  ```
- Por último, si quieres sobrecargar el operador[] para que puedas obtener el nombre del aldeano directamente de la civilización en una posición determinada sería con esta función:

  ```
   string Civilizacion::operator[](size_t n){
       if (n >= aldeanos.size()) {
           //No es válido
           return "";
       }
       return (aldeanos.begin() + n)->getNombreA();
   }
  ```

  De esta forma podrías comparar un string con el nombre del atributo "nombre" del aldeano usando el operador [] sobre la clase Aldeano haciendo lo siguiente:

  ```
   Civilizacion civ;

   //aldeanos de civ inicializados correctamente

   if(civ[0] == nombre){
       cout << "El nombre " << civ[0] << " coincide con el filtrado" << endl;
   }
  ```